# Can i get info about notification (apn)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, push-notification

Can I get list of push notifications (APNS notifications) for my app when app became from background to foreground mode?
**In foreground mode** i can receive info about push notification in callback

> -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

**Other case:**

My app receive push notification, when app **in background mode**. 
After this i **click on app icon**, and i want to get info about received notification. How can i get this info?

If i click **directly on the notification (not on app icon)**, in background mode, then callback **didReceiveRemoteNotification is call**.

Comment: if you are talking about [APNS - Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html), they arrive when they arrive (and the OS displays them accordingly - depending on if your app is in the foreground or not).  Or are you talking about different kind of notifications, NOT APNS?  Like status changes on a server or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I get list of push notifications (APNS notifications) for my app when app became from background to foreground mode?

No. There is no list. You can only get one notification at once. When the users iPhone is offline and you send 5 notifications the user will only get the last one you have send.

If the user starts your app using the open action on the notification you will get it on start using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

**Other Case**

> My app receive push notification, when app in background mode. After this i click on app icon, and i want to get info about received notification. How can i get this info?

You can't. When the user closes the notification and opens you app later it is already gone and there is no way to access it.

When you send push notifications you probably have a server reachable over the internet, where you register the devices of the user.

The usual way to handle this is to store the notifications on this server and query it on app launch... so use the notification just to notify the user to start your app and then check your server on launch of the app for whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Once your application reaches foreground and actively running, the notification alerts like sound, alert won't be displayed or you wont be notified.

But you will get a call back in the UIApplication Delegate that you can make use of it.

The api is,

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken`;

And, if your application is running in background, then the notification appears and only when you click on "View" button, you will get the call back in UIApplication delegate.

If you click on Close button,  you won't get the call back in the application.